# Do we need to configure SMTP on our server if using external smtp?

Tags: magento2, email, smtp

i'm using mageplaza's SMTP extension for magento 2.

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-smtp/

I have configured the smtp with smtp.office365.com and when sending the test email it is giving following error.

> Could not open socket: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to
>   tcp://smtp.office365.com:587 (Permission denied)

So is this issue on server settings or in magento side ? 
Also i have setup the linux server for the magento installation. 
Do need to install configure the SMTP for this server also ?

Comment: Have you tried gmail SMTP to see if it is working correctly to send email

Comment: `stream_socket_client()` is used for: Open Internet or Unix domain socket connection

The error seems connected to Network Layer, please try to run: `traceroute smtp.office365.com` to check where the connection gets terminated (Outgoing Firewall Rules @ Your Server might be blocking the Data Flow to smtp.office365.com)

Comment: Add your admin configuration image here